# making a post in an array correctly in php

Tags: php, arrays, post

after following this link `https://www.paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding?country.x=GB&exp=guest&flow=1-P&locale.x=en_GB&token=EC-9MC96353N3157960M`

i get the following

`https://www.jotform.com/uploads/forum/evedesh/1478100054ppss2.png`

after entering the data and sending it to the server i get the post shown in the example i want an array for that post to be included in php page

this post is send to the server this way and i want to include it in php file but it should be made in an array to be sent to the server. below is my trial but it is wrong please help in correcting it

post=

```
data":{"user":{"first_name":"","last_name":","email":"","password":"karem321K","countryOfResidence":"GB","country":"LK","dob_day":"19","dob_month":"12","dob_year":"1980","nationality":"LK"},"billing_address":{"line1":"rtjkykuytlkyukyu","city":"rhyurtjyt","postal_code":"54784","country":"LK"},"shipping_address":{"first_name":"tryhtrjtr","last_name":"trjrytrj","line1":"rtjkykuytlkyukyu","city":"rhyurtjyt","postal_code":"54784","country":"LK"},"phone":{"type":"Mobile","number":"245 478 457","countryCode":"94"},"marketing_optin":true,"shipping_address_validation":false,"poma_flow":false,"prox_flow":false,"testParams":{},"content_identifier":"LK:en:2.0.287:signupTerms.signupC","card":{"type":"MASTERCARD","number":"5413272585970408","security_code":"245","expiry_month":"01","expiry_year":"2020"},"skipInitiateAuth":true},"meta":{"token":"EC-88Y847017G447794R","calc":"cd18bf8034943","csci":"2e6ac6a6f5b2479fa687a77f2735fe10","locale":{"country":"LK","language":"en"},"state":"ui_checkout_guest","app_name":"xoonboardingnodeweb"}}
```

i coded it that way but i think it is incorrect
               $link = "paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding/api/onboard/guest";

```
            $post = [
    'data' => [
        'user' => [
            'first_name' => 'ytjkuk',
            'last_name' => 'tyktyku',
            'email' => 'j55555hgj@tjj.com',
            'password' => 'karem321K',
            'countryOfResidence' => 'GB',
            'country' => 'LK',
            'dob_day' => '19',
            'dob_month' => '12',
            'dob_year' => '1980',
            'nationality' => 'lk',
        ],
        'billing_address' => [
            'line1' => 'tuyttj',
            'city' => 'yjytjytj',
            'postal_code' => '54787',
            'country' => 'lk',
        ],
        'shipping_address' => [
            'first_name' => 'ytjkuk',
            'last_name' => 'tyktyku',
            'line1' => 'tuyttj',
            'city' => 'yjytjytj',
            'postal_code' => '54787',
            'country' => 'lk',
        ],
        'phone' => [
            'type' => 'Mobile',
            'number' => '245 478 457',
            'countryCode' => '94',
        ],
        'marketing_optin' => true,
        'shipping_address_validation' => false,
        'poma_flow' => false,
        'prox_flow' => false,
        'testParams' => [],
        'content_identifier' => "LK:en:2.0.287:signupTerms.signupC",
        'card' => [
            'type' => 'MASTERCARD',
            'number' => $ccn,
            'security_code' => $cvv,
            'expiry_month' => $ccmon,
            'expiry_year' => $ccyear,
        ],
        'skipInitiateAuth' => true,
    ],
    'meta' => [
        'token' => $token[1],
        'calc' => $calc[1],
        'csci' => $sci[1],
        'locale' => [
            'country' => 'LK',
            'language' => 'en',
        ],
        'state' => "ui_checkout_guest",
        'app_name' => "xoonboardingnodeweb",
    ]
];


$s = _curl($link, $post, $cookie);
```

please help in correcting that post in php

Comment: Hi Kem50, what do you expect us to do? I don't understand. Please explain briefly what you have did with the code so we can help you.

Comment: this post is send to the server this way and i want to include it in php file but it should be made in an array to be sent to the server. below is my trial but it is wrong please help in correcting it

Comment: Koen Hollander U THERE?

Comment: What's going on with your quotes in the `post=` part of your question? They're all kinds of messed up…

Answer (score 1):

To do a PHP POST request containing fields from `$POST_ASSOC_ARRAY` via CURL:

```
$c = curl_init(); //OPEN CURL HANDLE
$url = "locationScript.php"; // URL
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL,$url); //SET URL 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true); //SET MODE TO POST
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($POST_ASSOC_ARRAY)); //SET POST FIELDS
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //RETURN STRING
$output = curl_exec ($c); //EXECUTE

curl_close ($c); //CLOSE OPEN HANDLE

var_dump($output); //DUMP OUTPUT VIA VAR_DUMP
```

Comment: i need add post here     $link = "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding/api/onboard/guest"; 
    $post = "i need add post here";  
    $s = _curl($link,$post,$cookie);

Comment: Also note that http_build_query will only go 1 level deep if i recall correctly.